# Android keyboard layout language

Tags: android, keyboard-events, keyboard-layout, android-input-method

Writing a dictionary application for android. 
Want to set translation direction in accord with current input language (to be more precise, language of letters displayed on soft keyboard). For example, we got language pair English-French. What I want is, when user inputs English letters (English keyboard layout displayed) translation direction is straight, and when keyboard layout changes to French, translation direction also changes to inverted.

So, question is: is there any event in an android Input Method Framework, which allows to track this layout changing. If there is not, maybe there is some standard tricks to do what I need?

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I investigated there was no way to do that. So I made a custom keyboard to send a custom event (InputType) to my dictionary application.